# Precise vertical alignment into a TD element

Tags: css, html, html-table, alignment

I have a problem aligning objects inside the TD elements of a table. See the image below. I would like the text and input forms to be vertically near to line under them (which is the table collapsed border).

I succeded in getting text to be near the line but still, I can't do the same thing with the `input` forms. Do you have any suggestion ?

The `span` I used to align the text part is :

```
#tbAggiungiTitolo span.vicinoAlBordo {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Wrapping the same `span` around the `input` elements does not work.

Upon request, I add relevant part of the HTML code:

```
<table id="tbAggiungiTitolo">
<tr class="dataLine"> <td class="nome" > 
     <span class="vicinoAlBordo"> Prezzo di mercato corrente </span>
     <td class="spazio"> 
     <td class="valore"> 
     <!-- <span class="vicinoAlBordo">  -->
     <input type="text" name="perzzoDiMercatoCorrente"> 
     <!-- </span> -->
<tr class="dataLine"> <td class="nome" > 
.....
```

[image]

Comment: Can we also get the html for the table and the styling of the input boxes?

Comment: `vertical-align: baseline|bottom|middle|sub|super|text-bottom|text-top|top|inherit`

Comment: @Masiama, there is a designer in my group, you know as they are, "a little bit up", "a little bit down" they say.  These row classese are not what I'am looking for, but I will try some the keywords you listed and I never used. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Paige Mainke, ok I will add part of html to the post.

Comment: I solved, @Masiama suggestion was useful. This is what i made: 1) in `tr` style change `line-height:30` with `height:30`. 2) In `td` style I set `vertical-align:bottom`. 3) in `span` and `input` style now I use the `margin-bottom` to set a precise distance from the bottom line. It  Works ! Great ! I love this website, thank you all.